# Novice question on measure theory

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the theorem below and have been stuck on this point so would appreciate some help. The theorem says X is a mapping from $\Omega$ to $\Omega '$ , and $B'$ is the borel sets generated by $\Omega '$, then why do we need $B' = \sigma (C')$? I would have assumed that by the minimalism argument either $B' = \sigma (\Omega')$ or $\Omega ' \subset C' $. In either case, I am confused as to why we need this extra $C'$ in the theorem. Could someone please clarify what I am missing?[image]

The defns are provided in a section prior

[image]

Comment: I don‘t think $\Omega‘$ is assumed to be a topolpgical space. Rather $B‘$ should denote some arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C‘$.

Comment: The theorem basically states: to see if a mapping is measurable you only have to test it on generators and not the whole sigma algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the theorem is if you want to know if $X$ is measurable, you don't have to consider every set in the codomain $\sigma$-algebra -- rather, you can just check a collection of them that generates the $\sigma$-algebra you want.

Example: suppose the codomain is $\Omega' = [0, 1)$, with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B'$ generated by $\mathcal C' = \{[0, \frac 1 4), [\frac 1 4, \frac 1 2), [\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4), [\frac 3 4, 1)\}$. In this case, $\mathcal C'$ is a small collection of just 4 sets, but $\mathcal B'$ has $2^4 = 16$ sets. If you wanted to verify measurability of $X$, it would be more convenient to look just at those 4 sets in $\mathcal C'$ and not at all 16 sets in $\mathcal B'$. This convenience pays dividends for infinite $\sigma$-algebras where it's easy to describe a collection of generators.

(Note that $2^{\Omega'} = 2^{[0, 1)}$ would be *much, much* too big a space to consider here.)

Comment: I guess my question is why have a $C'$ at all? Why not just use $\Omega '$?. That is by defn. the generator, and the minimal generator, isnt it? Updated my description. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It doesn't need to be the case that $\Omega'$ generates $\mathcal B'$ in any meaningful way. In my example, $\Omega' = [0, 1)$, but there's no way to reconstruct the $\mathcal B'$ I gave from that. The difficulty here is that the space $\Omega$ usually has a power set that is much "larger" than the desired $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Sid I think you are confused. Omega is an ordinary set here. A generator of a sigma algebra of subsets of Omega would be a set of subsets of Omega.

Comment: ok, so it is an ordinary set. I guess that was my confusion. I just figured that since $\Omega$ is an abstract set, which is never going to be instantiated, might as well choose the most convenient one :D.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you're being given a criterion that saves you the trouble of having to check that the preimage of *every* measurable set is measurable, as the standard definition of measurability would have you do. You only have to check the ones in the generating set $\mathcal C'$.

Also, I don't see any assumptions about Borel anything in the proposition.